# Creating Django Package and View Authentication

Tags: python, django, module

In a Django project, I have created an app (via *python manage.py **startapp***) that I would like to turn into an importable python package now, that the project is done. The idea is to reuse its functionality in a new project of mine.

The project structure is - for example - as follows:

```
myproject/            # the project/site root
    manage.py
    myproject/...     # the core app of a project
    templates/...     # project template folder
    static/...        # project static folder
    myapp/            # <----------- App in question
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py      # <----------- LoginRequiredMixin and @login_required
        urls.py
        tests/...
        migrations/...
        templates/...
        static/...

    myapp2/ 
    myapp3/ 
    myapp4/ 
    ...
```

```py
# In views.py I have several Classes/Functions 
# with the authentification mixin/decorators

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

...

class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,...):
    pass # for views

@login_required
def someFunction(request):
    pass # for functions
```

It was not a problem to factor out the app into a package, since it is nicely contained in the myapp/ folder. I moved it into separate folder, added setup.cfg and setup.py and created a package successfully:

```
pyapp-package/
    setup.cfg    # <-- setuptools configuration
    setup.py     # <-- setup()

    admin.py     # the rest of the app
    apps.py
    ...
```

My problem (and hence the question) is, how to make Authentication of this app **optional**, when I Install it in the new project via settings.py?

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp-package',             # <-- including my app in the new project

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I considered stripping ***LoginRequiredMixin*** and ***@login_required*** from ***views.py*** and then handle this functionality in ***urls.py*** of the new project but I don't see a standard solution to this problem documented in the docs. Is this a viable option or does one need to solve this differently.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you following way. You should create a variable in the settings.py file, and then according to this value, you determine whether you need or not authentication.

**settings.py**

```
...

LOGIN_REQUIRED = True

...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from <project_name>.settings import LOGIN_REQUIRED


# Determine whether we need or not authentication.
if LOGIN_REQUIRED:
    class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, ...):
        pass

    @login required
    def some_function(request):
        pass
else:
    class SomeView(...):
        pass

    def some_function(request):
        pass
```

I don't know yet how to create functions' and classes' prototypes to follow the DRY principle. Maybe somebody else can help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! The part with the settings.py is how I would tackle the problem as well. The only problem is the DRY principle, which would be violated in views.py module. I know there is a possibility to 'hack' a bit with function calls in urls.py, but this seems such a common issue I was sure there needs to be a better way :) Thanks for your reply!